# Layer not generating correctly when running Raster Fillnodata in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, landsat-7

Using QGIS 3.4.5 I am attempting to fill a landsat 7 band raster layer as the image contains diagonal lines because of the scan line corrector issue. I'm using the raster analysis no fill data tool but the layer does not generate correctly as the screen shot below. I've tried altering the setting to every conceivable combination but no success.
[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug. I reproduced the error when I downloaded a Landsat 7 image into a folder whose name has a space. Will you change the name of your folder `Forest of Bowland` to something like `Forest_of_Bowland` and try again?

Comment: Yes will do thanks - let you know how I get on

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito - it works! Bad folder naming on my part

Comment: Thanks @Sean for confirmation. Given this is a bug we'd better close this post now.